# Struct table. if... else if... else if... alternative

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement

I made an "alternative" to a giant list of if.. else if.. else if..... statements:

```
#include <iostream>

void test_func_ref();

struct transition_table
{
    char trans_key_1;
    char trans_key_2;
    void(&func_ref)();
};

int main() {

    transition_table test_table[] = {
        { 'A','B', test_func_ref },
        { 'B','Q', test_func_ref },
        { 'D','S', test_func_ref },
        { 'E','Q', test_func_ref },
        { 'B','W', test_func_ref },
        { 'F','Q', test_func_ref },
        { 'B','S', test_func_ref },
        { 'S','Q', test_func_ref },
        { 'B','X', test_func_ref },
        { 'R','R', test_func_ref },
        { 'B','O', test_func_ref },
        { 'K','Q', test_func_ref },
        { 'J','I', test_func_ref }
    };

    char choice1,choice2;

    std::cin >> choice1 >> choice2;

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(test_table) / sizeof(test_table[0])); i++) {
        if (choice1 == test_table[i].trans_key_1)
            if (choice2 == test_table[i].trans_key_2) {
                //Code here
                std::cout << std::endl;
                std::cout << "This is equal to table row " << i << std::endl;
                test_table[i].func_ref();
            }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void test_func_ref() {
    std::cout << "Voided function called" << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any other (prettier? efficient?) way of doing this without a block of if..else if statements?

I assume that this method is slightly slower than a list of if...else if statements?

Comment: Have you done any searching for something like "table driven state machine"? That seems at least very close to what you have here.

Comment: `std::map` instead of C-style array will be a bit faster

Comment: Another option is to make up a macro that will produce a unique integer for each possible pair of character inputs, and use that as index for a `switch` statement

Comment: if you transition_table were arranged alphabetically, you could use a binary search, which might be a bit faster.

Comment: You can `#define CASE(x,y) (((x)<<8)|((y)<<0))` and then instead of those two `if` statements use: `if (CASE(test_table[i].trans_key_1,test_table[i].trans_key_2)==CASE(choice1,choice2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using your list like a look-up table to find a unique value matching a pair, you can use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void test_func(char, char);

typedef void(&func_ref)(char, char);

static map<int,func_ref> tbl = {
    { 'A' << 8 | 'B', test_func },
    { 'B' << 8 | 'Q', test_func },
    { 'D' << 8 | 'S', test_func },
    ...
    { 'K' << 8 | 'Q', test_func },
    { 'J' << 8 | 'I', test_func }
};

int main() {
    char a, b;
    while (cin >> a >> b) {
        auto fp = tbl.find(a << 8 | b);
        if (fp != tbl.end()) {
            fp->second(a, b);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void test_func(char a, char b) {
    std::cout << "Voided function called: " << a << ":" << b << std::endl;
}
```

The `'A' << 8 | 'B'` expressions provide a trick to combining two characters into a single `int` key by shifting the first `char` into the higher 8 bits of the `int`, and OR-ing the second `char` into the lower 8 bits.

Note that lookup no longer requires an explicit loop in your code, because `tbl.find(a << 8 | b)` call does the searching for you.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/bvZ2Xt)